# changing the order of the data inside of a file using seekg, tellg function

Tags: c++, winsock, seekg

I'm new to c++ programming. I have a small excercise which enables the use of the following: using of windows socket programming, using of window api functions (CreateFile, ReadFile, and WriteFile), and using of seekg, seekp, tellg, and tellp functions.

Here's what's happening in my code,

1. Open a `.txt` file that has URLs inside (reddit.com,stackoverflow.com,google.com) and then read the URLs and put inside of `strVal`.
2. Then I split the value of the data inside of `strVal` using delimiter `","` then the loop starts.
3. Then the windows socket programming will start.
4. Inside of the loop it will get the HTTP request of each URLs and will ask the request type(`POST` or `GET`).
5. Once the answer from the request was received, the data will be inside of Buffer.
6. Then I will open a `.txt` file to put the received request of the 3 domains.

**Example** [here's the result of output.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNKxx.png)

The result is fine and the program is working on this part but for the last requirement of the program, they want me to change the order of the answered data inside of the `.txt` file using seekg, seekp, tellg, and tellp.

I tried to implement those functions and here's my code.

```
fstream fs0 ("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\My Documents\\output.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::app);
ofstream fs1 ("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\My Documents\\output1.txt", ios::out | ios::app);

//1st
fs0.seekg(2020, ios::beg);

char ab[2020];
fs0.read(ab, sizeof(ab));

//2nd
fs0.seekg(0, ios::cur);

char dc[2020];
fs0.read(dc, sizeof(dc));

//3rd 
fs0.seekg(0, ios::beg);

char abc[2000];
fs0.read(abc, sizeof(abc));

fs1.write(ab, sizeof(ab));
fs1.write(dc, sizeof(dc));
fs1.write(abc, sizeof(abc));

fs0.close();
fs1.close()
```

I just opened `.txt` file  where the data inserted then just read the data using seekg then put it inside of a buffer then output. There's no sense because what if there's another domain inserted inside of the `.txt` file.

Now, ***my concern is on this part. Based on my code how can I change the order of the data inside of the txt file using seekg, seekp, tellg, and tellp?***

Here's my overall code,

```
    int main()
    {
    //getting the data
    HANDLE openFile;
    //HANDLE openFile1;
    HANDLE putdataFile;
    BOOL rewriFile;
    //BOOL rewriFile1;
    char *strVal;
    //char *strVal1;

    char* point;
    //char* point1;
    DWORD dwNoBytetoRead = 0;
    //DWORD dwNoBytetoRead1 = 0;
    DWORD dwNoByteWritten = 0;
    char dataextracted[] = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\My Documents";
    //40 dash
    string dash1 = "\n--------------------";
    string dash2 = "--------------------\n";

    //connecting to the server
    SOCKET Socket;
    SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;
    struct hostent *host;
    char buffer[10000];
    int dataLen;
    int i = 0;
    //get
    string http1 = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: ";
    string http2 = "\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";
    //post
    string http3 = "POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: ";
    string http4 = "\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";
    //winsock startup
    WSAData wsaData;

    //1 or 2
    string input;

    //start of program.................................

    //open file
    openFile = CreateFile(L"C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\My Documents\\url.txt", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    //allocating memory
    LARGE_INTEGER fs;
    GetFileSizeEx(openFile, &fs);
    unsigned long long fSize = fs.QuadPart;
    strVal = (char*) malloc (fSize + 1);
    memset(strVal, 0, fSize + 1);

    //reading the content
    rewriFile = ReadFile(openFile, strVal, fSize, &dwNoBytetoRead, NULL);
    cout << "The URL/s " << strVal << endl << endl;

    CloseHandle(openFile);

    //split string
    point = strtok(strVal, ",\r\n");

    while (point != NULL) {
    //get
    string httpRequestget = http1 + point + http2;
    //post
    string httpRequestpost = http3 + point + http4;
    //checking kung successful yung wsastartup
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0) {
        cout << "WSAStartup failed.\n";
        system("pause");
        //return 1;
    }

    //connects to domain
    Socket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
        host = gethostbyname(point);

    SockAddr.sin_port=htons(80);
    SockAddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long*)host->h_addr);

    //just to check kung connected or may error pala
      if(connect(Socket,(SOCKADDR*)(&SockAddr),sizeof(SockAddr)) != 0){
    cout << "Could not connect";
    system("pause");
    //return 1;
      }else{
      cout << "You are now connected to " << point << endl;
      }

    //choice 1 or 2
    cout << "Options to request\n";
    cout << "[1] HTTP request using GET\n";
    cout << "[2] HTTP request using POST\n";
    cout << "Choose an option: ";
    cin >> input;
    cout << endl;

    if (input == "1"){
    // Sending a HTTP-GET-Request to the Web Server
    int sentBytes = send(Socket, httpRequestget.c_str(), strlen(httpRequestget.c_str()),0);
    } else if (input == "2") {
    // Sending a HTTP-POST-Request to the Web Server
    int sentBytes = send(Socket, httpRequestpost.c_str(), strlen(httpRequestpost.c_str()),0);
    }

    // Receiving and Displaying an answer from the Web Server
    ZeroMemory(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    recv(Socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);

    //put data in a file
    putdataFile = CreateFile(L"C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\My Documents\\output.txt", FILE_APPEND_DATA, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    string dash3 = dash1 + point + dash2;
    //write dash
    rewriFile = WriteFile(putdataFile, dash3.c_str(), strlen(dash3.c_str()), &dwNoByteWritten, NULL);

    //write the content
    rewriFile = WriteFile(putdataFile, buffer, 2000, &dwNoByteWritten, NULL);

    CloseHandle(putdataFile);

    // Cleaning up Windows Socket Dependencies
     closesocket(Socket);
     WSACleanup();

        point = strtok(NULL, ",\r\n");

    }
    cout << endl << "Data is downloaded here: " << dataextracted << endl << endl;

    fstream fs0 ("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\My Documents\\output.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::app);
    ofstream fs1 ("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\My Documents\\output1.txt", ios::out | ios::app);

    //1st
    fs0.seekg(2020, ios::beg);

    char ab[2020];
    fs0.read(ab, sizeof(ab));

    //2nd
    fs0.seekg(0, ios::cur);

    char dc[2020];
    fs0.read(dc, sizeof(dc));

    //3rd 
    fs0.seekg(0, ios::beg);

    char abc[2000];
    fs0.read(abc, sizeof(abc));

    fs1.write(ab, sizeof(ab));
    fs1.write(dc, sizeof(dc));
    fs1.write(abc, sizeof(abc));

    fs0.close();
    fs1.close();
    system("pause");l

    return 0;
      }
```

Comment: It is convention that the contents of the link need to be within the question/post. So, you may put the content from this link "example here's the result of output.txt" within the post; use _edit_.

Comment: IMHO, your question is too extensive. You should try to focus on what is really missing. Where is "2020" coming from as the size of `ab` and `dc`?